# Air flow over an airfoil

Tags: aerodynamics

[image: picture of flow over an airfoil]
We know that in real viscous flow, boundary layer exists around the airfoil and there will be a separation point which flow starts to separate from the back of the airfoil( velocity gradient equal zero at separation point). If the flow speed increases, will separation occur earlier or later?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but is not really on-topic here.

Comment: Aviation.SE is a better fit for this question.

Comment: @OrganicMarble thanks, then what topic should it be?

Comment: @Hobbes I don't find aviation in topics. And what's the meaning of SE?

Comment: SE = StackExchange. You're looking for https://aviation.stackexchange.com

Comment: We mean that your question is not appropriate for this particular stack exchange site, and are suggesting that you try aviation.stackexchange.com

Comment: @OrganicMarble got it I find the aviation site now thanks

Comment: and "try" means 1) go to [Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/) and look around at the existing questions and answers, 2) consider joining that site, and 3) if you think you have a new and different question from those that already have answer..., that's a little more detailed than this one, and shows some evidence that you've done some reading first, *then* post a question there. Have fun, there are [almost 200 SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name) to choose from!